# Reg Ex strictly match word start with a pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to extract a text after a sequence. But I have multiple sequences. the regex should ideally match first occurrence of any of these sequences.

my sequences are

`PIN, PIN :, PIN IN, PIN IN:, PIN OUT,PIN OUT :`

So I came up with the below regex

`(PIN)(\sOUT|\sIN)?\:?\s*`

It is doing the job except that the regex is also matching strings like

> quote lupin in, pippin etc.

My question is how can I strictly select the string that match the pattern being the whole word

note: I tried `^(PIN)(\sOUT|\sON)?\:?\s*` but of no use.
I'm new to java, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s always recommended to have [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/regex/Pattern.html) at hand when using regular expressions.

There, under [Boundary matchers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds) we find:

> `\b`          A word boundary

So you may use the pattern `\bPIN(\sOUT|\sIN)?:?\s*` to enforce that `PIN` matches at the beginning of a word only, i.e. stands at the beginning of a string/line or is preceded by non-word characters like space or punctuation. A boundary only matches a position, rather than characters, so if a preceding non-word character makes this a word boundary, the character still is not part of the match.

Note that the first `(…)` grouping was unnecessary for the literal match `PIN`, further the colon `:` has no special meaning and doesn’t need to be escaped.